# How to join 2 tables with two primary key columns by Full outer Join in Sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, where-clause, hana, outer-join

I need to join two dummy tables(one for actual amount and one for budgeted amounts) with Account table which have All account codes and Project Table which have all project Codes,

here my query,

```
TblActual :=select Actual."AcctCode",Actual."Project",sum(Actual."DocTotal")
from Actual
group by Actual."AcctCode",Actual."Project";

TblBuget := Select Budget."AcctCode",Budget."PrjCode",Sum(Budget."DocTotal")
Form Budget
Group by Budget."AcctCode",Budget."PrjCode";

Select 
Project."PrjCode",Account."AcctCode",Account."AcctName",
:TblActual."Amount" as "Actual",:TblBuget."Amount" as "Budget"
From Account 
Full outer Join :TblActual on Account."AcctCode" = :TblActual."AcctCode"
Full outer Join :TblBuget on Account."AcctCode" = :TblBuget."AcctCode"
Left Join Project on (:TblActual."Project"= Project."PrjCode" and :TblBuget."PrjCode" = Project."PrjCode" )
where  Project."PrjCode"= xxx;
```

If I need to filter by a project I only received Accounts which both tables have the project and account code. But there are some accounts in budget table with this project code but not in the actual table and
Some accounts are in Actual table with this Project code and not in Budget table.

I need to get all this data without duplicating the account code.How to do that?

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. [ask] Stop trying to code your overall goal & explain what you expected instead from the given code & why.

Comment: This involves a common error where people want some joins, each possibly involving a different key, of some subqueries, each possibly involving join and/or aggregation, but they erroneously try to do all the joining then all the aggregating or to aggregate over previous aggregations. Write separate aggregations over appropriate rows and/or aggregate a case statement picking rows; join on common unique column sets. Sometimes DISTINCT aggregation can pick the right value after a non-key join.